# Is there a Linux command for string subtraction between columns?

Tags: awk, uniq, vcf-variant-call-format

I'm processing some SNP column into vcf format.

the input columns are as following :

```
ref     ALT 
A       A G 
A       A T 
T       C T 
G       G T 
A       A G 
C       C G T 
G       A G 
T       C T 
T       A G T
```

expected output :

```
ref     ALT
A       G
A       T
T       C
G       T
A       G
C       G,T
G       A
T       C
T       A,G
```

Comment: Could you explain the logic need to get expected output from given input? Also, do not assume that everybody would know what is SNP or vcf. If this is related to bioinformatics, https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com might suit you better. And it is expected that you show what you've done to solve this problem yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR>1{sub($1," ",$2); gsub(/^ +| +$/,"",$2); gsub(/ +/,",",$2)} 1' file
ref     ALT
A       G
A       T
T       C
G       T
A       G
C       G,T
G       A
T       C
T       A,G
```

The above will only work when $1 doesn't contain RE metachars and can't be a substring of any of the strings in $2.

Comment: I have tried this command line, the output is just what I need, Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is nothing elegant here, just iterating through the fields on each line and deciding whether to print or not after comparing with the first column.

```
NR == 1 {print; next}
{
    printf "%s", $1
    sep = "\t"
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) {
        if ($i != $1) {
            printf "%s%s", sep, $i
            sep = ","
        }
    }
    print ""
}

$ awk -f a.awk file
ref     ALT
A   G
A   T
T   C
G   T
A   G
C   G,T
G   A
T   C
T   A,G
```

Comment: I want use it in pipeline ,so I converted  the awk file to one line :                                                                                                          cat inputf.file | awk 'NR == 1 {print; next}  {printf "%s", $1; sep = "\t"; for (i = 2; i <= 
NF; ++i) {if ($i != $1) { printf "%s%s", sep, $i; sep = "," } } print "" }'|less     The output is just what I need, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using perl instead of awk allows for a short one-liner:

```
$ perl -lane 'print $F[0], "\t", join(",", grep { $_ ne $F[0] } @F)' input.txt
ref ALT
A   G
A   T
T   C
G   T
A   G
C   G,T
G   A
T   C
T   A,G
```

Comment: Dear Shawn, I dont know too much about Perl, anyway  this line works fine for me .Thank !